# get all ip address from subnet mask

Tags: networking

I have this IP list shown below. How i can calculate all ip addresses from that in Linux? Is there some tools that can calculate that for me ? I need that to check if i have not banned some cloudflare IP's. As firewall i am using shorewall and i am banning with fail2ban single IP. As i know, then i cannot detect subent mask from IP adress, right?

```
204.93.240.0/24
204.93.177.0/24
199.27.128.0/21
173.245.48.0/20
103.22.200.0/22
141.101.64.0/18
108.162.192.0/18
190.93.240.0/20
188.114.96.0/20
```

Comment: What do you mean by calculate all IPs? You already have a list of IPs. Do you want to change 11.22.33.0/5 to 11.22.33.0 11.22.33.1 ... 11.22.33.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I have understood your question, but if you want to expand a list of IP ranges to all the IPs said ranges contain, try this:

```
$ perl -ne '/(.+)\.(\d+)\/(\d+)$/; print "$1.$_\n" foreach($2..$3)' iplist.txt > IPs
```

This will create a file called `IPs` containing:

```
204.93.240..0
204.93.240..1
204.93.240..2
204.93.240..3
 ...

188.114.96..18
188.114.96..19
188.114.96..20
```

You can then loop through the file and apply whatever tool you need (ping, for example) to each IP:

```
$ while read ip; do ping $ip; done < IPs
```

You can also combine the two commands if you do not want to create a file with all the IPs:

```
$ perl -ne '/(.+)\.(\d+)\/(\d+)$/; print "$1.$_\n" foreach($2..$3)' iplist.txt | while read ip; do ping $ip; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and the Perl script in the accepted answer didn't work for me as it only took into consideration the last byte of the IPv4.

So I came up with my own implementation which is available in both source code and binary format for different systems here: [CIDR-to-IP-list](https://github.com/tanis2000/cidr-to-iplist)

Answer (score 0):

No, ever since [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation) was introduced, you can't derive the netmask from the IP address. You can calculate the broadcast address (the highest address in the subnet) by converting the network address to an integer, add 2^(32-netmask), and convert the result back to [quad-dotted decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation) notation.